# How to manage monetary display in 2023?

Tags: currency

Based on this [year 2008](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=3876.0.html) thread and a few earlier threads on civi.stackexchange regarding the matter.  Now (CiviCRM 5.56.2), when "Monetary Amount Display" on civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1 is deprecated and gone, how do we, say, remove decimals from currency display, apart from altering `CRM_Utils_Money`?

Comment: Same interest in altering: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1494#note_65518

Answer (score 1):

While not a supported option, theoretically you can replace `\Civi::$statics[$cacheKey];` from https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/b0fff1c64cf3dd2e40b248b3b067ca30de09aeee/Civi/Core/Format.php#L220, probably in hook_civicrm_config in an extension, with a modified $formatter object that does what you want.

e.g. in hook_civicrm_config

```
$cacheKey = <figure out cachekey>
$formatter = \Civi::$statics[$cacheKey];
// make some changes to $formatter here
\Civi::$statics[$cacheKey] = $formatter;
```

But it would be nicer if there was a supported way to change the parameters that the formatter object uses.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a copy of Money.php in custom php directory and alter   getCurrencyPrecision() ?

Comment: It makes upgrades harder if you need to sync changes every time, but yes that should work too.

Comment: Indeed; I was thinking about a tiny extension which would extend the CRM_Utils_Money class, just not sure which hook to use.

Comment: If we assume the target audience for customizing is developers, then I think the solution to that would be to change [this line in core](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/be1dda3865ab9e84ab5af740ad7fcb6bebaa4b9e/Civi.php#L138) so that it acts like a service, similar to [the logger](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/be1dda3865ab9e84ab5af740ad7fcb6bebaa4b9e/Civi.php#L96), so that you could replace it like the way [monolog does](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/monolog/-/blob/81786bd2b346ec8bb7d1227ef0c4522ddc6d644c/monolog.php#L150).

Comment: That would replace the entire Format class not just the money formatter, but it's the same idea, you'd extend it, and just override the part you need.